# MVC2/3 ChildActionOnly controller methods are accessible for Googlebot?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, googlebot

If have this issue for already several months and thought that I showed to Googlebot in early versions of app that controller method. But recently added new one - `LatestNews` also marked with `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute

**Problem**
Elmah sometimes catching the following exception:

```
The action 'LatestNews' is accessible only by a child request.
```

from

```
Connection: Keep-alive Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com Host: soldiez.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

I have the following action declaration (a bit simplified of course)

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public virtual ActionResult LatestNews()
{
   var data = DataManager.CollectNews();
   return PartialView( data );
}
```

and View is called like that:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContent" runat="server"><%   
   Html.RenderAction( MVC.Home.LatestNews() );
%></asp:Content>
```

I'm wondering how google could find that child action. I have never been deployed version without ChildActionOnly

I would be appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about this too much - the main thing is that the ChildAction attribute is working as expected.

Issues like this are often the result of greedy routes and mistyped links. You could download Glimpse (from nuget) so you can see exactly what routes are being matched but this won't help you find links that may have been mistyped (perhaps pointing to your child action).

Comment: Ben, thank you for your response. Actually I didn't worry about it for a couple of months but when recently was added new child action with the single call (see in topic) I was really amazed and confused. Just a think - can Google parse it if for some reason there was an exception on that page when bot was crauling it and it picked link from the stack trace (There is no custom error page for that place yet)?..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google Bot does not know anything any server language jargons. He only send a request to your server and then play with the returned response(which just include Html, js etc). He does not know about the url of your child action unless you have manually expose it.

Comment: True. And it should not know anything about that because this information is not populated to rendered html. But in fact in 2-3 days the code above was deployed I looked into exceptions log and found that child action was called several times by googlebot...